# How can I convert a float between 0 and 1 to an array index of size N?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, floating-point

I have a float value between 0 and 1 which represents the hue of a particular color.  How can I map that float value to an array index of some size.

So, say I wanted to create 128 "buckets" to sort my objects into, how can I convert the float value into an array index between 0-127 based on its value?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication, followed by rounding down.

```
arrayIndex = floor(floatingValue * numberOfBuckets)
```

Comment: Just watch out if `floatingValue == 1.0`.